# Estimation of the spectral condition using the Gerschgorin circle theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, symmetric-matrices, condition-number

I have been given the following exercise

> Use the Gerschgorin cirlce theorem to find an upper bound for the spectral condition of a matrix $A$ which is real, symmetric and diagonally dominant.

I guess we can also assume, that $A$ is invertible, because we defined the spectral condition only for invertible matrices.

I tried the following:
$$
\kappa_2(A) \overset{\text{def.}}{=} \Vert A \Vert_2 \Vert A^{-1} \Vert_2 = \varrho(A)\varrho(A^{-1})
$$
where $\varrho(M)$ is the spectral radius of $M$.

There is an easy way to bound $\varrho(A)$:
Using Gerschgorin and the diagonal dominance we get
$$
\vert \lambda - a_{jj} \vert \leq \sum_{l \neq j} a_{jl} \leq \vert a_{jj} \vert\\
\Rightarrow \vert \lambda - a_{jj} \vert + \vert a_{jj} \vert \leq 2\vert a_{jj} \vert
$$
and by the triangle inequality
$$
\vert \lambda \vert \leq \vert \lambda - a_{jj} \vert + \vert a_{jj} \vert \leq 2\vert a_{jj} \vert
$$
then we choose $\vert a_{jj} \vert$ maximal and so got $\varrho(A)$ bounded.

But bounding $\varrho(A^{-1})$ is rather difficult: I wanted to use $\varrho(A^{-1}) = 1/\min( \vert \text{eig}(A) \vert)$, but I have not found a way to lower bound $\min( \vert \text{eig}(A) \vert)$, which also seems intuitively impossible to me;
Just imagine the circles we get by using the inequality which we derived by using the diagonal dominance
$$
\vert \lambda - a_{jj} \vert \leq \vert a_{jj} \vert
$$
all of thous circles include the origin. I guess you see my problem.

I could lower bound $\min( \vert \text{eig}(A) \vert$ by not using the diagonal dominance, but I guess this would just ruin the whole point of this exercise.

Maybe I am overlooking something, or maybe there is an entirely different method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I used the triangle inequality correctly (at least as far as I can tell), I use some precision by that step, but I honestly do not care that much. My problem is mostly to find any bound for $\varrho(A^{-1})$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But this "use of some precision" loses you the non-zero lower bound. There are generalizations of the circle theorem that give stricter bounds, but with non-linear inequalities. For practical purposes  one would reduce the matrix to tridiagonal form first or even apply some rounds of the QR algorithm to get smaller radii around the diagonal entries.

Comment: @LutzLehmann sorry, the "use of some precision" is a typo and should be "loose of some precision"

Comment: It does not change the meaning, in the lower bound this loss of precision is exactly the distance to zero, you need the strictness of the diagonal dominance to bound the eigenvalues away from zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I already assumed $A$ to be invertible, so the zero itself is not a problem.

Comment: But you want a numerical estimate of the condition number, and there dividing by zero gives a rather impossible or meaningless bound.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I don't see where I divide by zero?

Comment: See the denominator in the last formula of the answer. With your kind of simplification the denominator becomes zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Now I understand what you mean. Yes, I saw that problem, but not using this simplification results in not using the diagonal dominance (or am I wrong here?). This is what I meant in my answer by saying that I found bounding but none for which I had to use the diagonal dominance. Edit: Maybe I understand now what happend, the diagonal dominance was not meant to make to bounding tighter, but just to prevent the denominator in the answer from getting zero. I have not thought that way because it doesn't say strictly diagonal dominant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Gerschgorin disc theorem, every eigenvalue of $A$ lies inside the union of the open Gerschgorin discs $\cup_{i=1}^n B(a_{ii},\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|)$. Since the $A$ in question is symmetric and diagonally dominant (I suppose the question means that $A$ is *strictly* diagonally dominant, otherwise the condition number of $A$ may not exist, such as when $A=0$), we have either
$$
0<a_{ii}-\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\le\lambda\le a_{ii}+\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|
$$
or
$$
a_{ii}-\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\le\lambda\le a_{ii}+\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|<0
$$
for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ in the disc (say, the $i$-th one) it belongs to. It follows that
$$
0<|a_{ii}|-\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\le|\lambda|\le |a_{ii}|+\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|
$$
in the disc that $\lambda$ belongs to. Consequently,
$$
\kappa_2(A)=\frac{|\lambda|_\max(A)}{|\lambda|_\min(A)}\le\frac{
\max_i\left\{|a_{ii}|+\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\right\},
}{
\min_i\left\{|a_{ii}|-\sum_{j\ne i}|a_{ij}|\right\}
}.
$$

Comment: @user1551 you divide by $\lambda_\max (A)$, should it not be $\min(\vert \lambda \vert)$? The smallest eigenvalue does not have to be the absolut smallest eigenvalue.

Comment: @Dominik You are right. It's fixed now.