# Estimate spectral radius of general square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

I have a large sparse $n \times n$ matrix $A$, which generally is not diagonally dominant. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3520110) provides an estimate assuming diagonal dominance, but it looks to be inappropriate for the non-diagonally dominant case (the numerator here would be negative).

I am aware of Krylov solvers that estimate eigenvalues en route to a solution; is there a more general way of directly estimating the spectral radius of a matrix with less cost than a full eigenvalue computation?

Some properties of $A$, if it matters:

- $A$ is invertible
- $A$ is usually symmetric
- $A$ has non-zero diagonal
- Coefficients of $A$ may be positive or negative

Comment: @BenGrossmann edited the post. $A$ has positive and negative entries (and many zeros).

Comment: Of the top of my head, the [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) method seems like a good candidate because computing products $Ax$ is relatively inexpensive. For non-sparse matrices, I'd be inclined to consider something more robust like [Rayleigh quotient iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient_iteration), but I'm not sure if there's a particularly quick way to solve sparse linear systems